# Hover sobre un elemento que esta tapado por otro

Tags: html, css, hover

sobre un elemento html (en mi caso un icono de lupa) quiero que al hacer hover me muestre una imagen, el caso es que la imagen tiene que estar por encima de la lupa una vez que entro en hover y si bien funciona no lo hace todo lo bien que deberia ya que se produce un bucle infinito entre la imagen y la lupa al censar el hover (ver con la consola), dejo ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
},false);
```

```css
*{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .lupa{
            background: teal;
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .lupa:hover ~ .imagen{
            display:block;
        }
        .imagen{
            background: tomato;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0px;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lupa">LUPA</div>
    <div class="imagen">IMAGEN</div>
</body>
</html>
```

como podria subsanar este problema? seria algo como detener la propagacion del hover?
La imagen tiene que ir si o si encima de la lupa una vez entra en hover

una solucion que se me ocurrio es hacer un span que este por encima de todo con posicion relativa a la lupa y dandole una opacidad 0 aun el hover lo toma, pero no se como hacer el hover en el css ya que el span ya no es el siguiente hermano de imagen, pongo ejemplo:

```css
*{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .lupa{
            background: teal;
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .lupaFake:hover ~ .imagen{
            display:block;
        }
        .imagen{
            background: tomato;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0px;
            display: none;
        }
        .lupaFake{
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background: turquoise;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity:0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lupa">LUPA <span class="lupaFake"></span></div>
    <div class="imagen">IMAGEN</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Y si lo manejas todo con JS? Es todo un problema que el elemento se renderice encima y deje de disparar el evento del mouse. Sería algo así:

```js
const lupaOn = false;
const targetImg = document.getElementById("targetImg");


function lupaEnter(e){
  targetImg.style.display = "block";
}

function lupaLeave(e){
  targetImg.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
*{
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }
        .lupa{
            background: teal;
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .imagen{
            background: tomato;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0px;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="lupa" onmouseleave="lupaLeave(this)" onmouseover="lupaEnter(this)">LUPA</div>
    <div class="imagen" id="targetImg">IMAGEN</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE

Usando solo CSS se me ocurrió darle prioridad al `div` de la lupa utilizando el índice z (así el elemento de la imagen no le salta encima y "desactiva" el evento) y esconderla utilizando el atributo de opacidad cuando el mouse está encima, espero que esta solución te sea más útil!

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.lupa {
  background: teal;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.lupa:hover {
  opacity: 0
}

.lupa:hover~.imagen {
  display: block;
}

.imagen {
  background: tomato;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="lupa">LUPA</div>
  <div class="imagen">IMAGEN</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias @FranAcuna por tu respuesta, sabia como hacerlo con js pero queria saber si lo podia hacer solo con css.      Una cosa curiosa, al menos para mi, si lo haces en js con delegacion al document sucede lo mismo que con css. Para q funcione hay q poner el evento al elemento lupa. Sera que css maneja los eventos tipo delegando?

Comment: Yo también tuve la misma idea y lo que hice fue ponerle un id a lupa y delegar el evento haciendo `document.getElementById()` y el resultado fue el mismo.

Comment: Te edité la pregunta con una solución que utiliza solo CSS.

Comment: perfecto, con ese hack funciona de maravilla, muchas Gracias!!